# Can this type of U-substitution work?

Tags: calculus

Definite Integral of $(3x+1)^{\sqrt{2}}$ with lower and upper bounds being 1 to 4, respectively. I know that commencing a u-sub with $u = 3x+1$ is a nice way to approach this problem, but I believe that a u-sub with $u = (3x+1)^{\sqrt{2}} can still work. I have have not yet been able to reach the right answer, however. 
Here is my work:

$\int_{1}^{4}(3x+1)^{\sqrt{2}} dx$

$u = (3x+1)^{\sqrt{2}}$ 
$du = \sqrt{2}(3x+1)^{\sqrt{2}- 1}  3 dx$

I ultimately end up with:
$\frac{1}{3*\sqrt{2}}$(integral sign with bounds 1 to 4) $u^{\sqrt{2}}$

and I notice, from the solutions I have seen, that having the $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ constant is where I messed up but I cannot see where I went wrong. Please help!

Comment: Oh dear. Please take a look at the MathJax tutorial so we can read your question. You have some of it right, but enclose the formatting in dollar signs!

Answer (score 2):

$$\int_{1}^{4}(3x+1)^{\sqrt{2}}\ dx$$
Apply u-substitution $u=3x+1$ and we get$$\implies\dfrac13\int u^{\sqrt{2}}\ du=\dfrac13\cdot \dfrac{(3x+1)^{\sqrt{2}+1}}{\sqrt{2}+1}=\dfrac{\sqrt{2}-1}{3}(3x+1)^{\sqrt{2}+1}$$

So, we got $\int(3x+1)^{\sqrt{2}}\ dx=\dfrac{\sqrt{2}-1}{3}(3x+1)^{\sqrt{2}+1}$

Now apply the bounds and we get $$\int_{1}^{4}(3x+1)^{\sqrt{2}}\ dx=\left[\dfrac{\sqrt{2}-1}{3}(3x+1)^{\sqrt{2}+1}\right]_{1}^{4}=\dfrac{\sqrt{2}\cdot13^{\sqrt{2}+1}-13^{\sqrt{2}+1}-2^{2\sqrt{2}+\frac52}+4^{\sqrt{2}+1}}{3}$$